# svhost.exe error on windows 2003 server

Tags: windows-server-2003

i have windows 2003 server

suddenly when i restart my server i got error svhost error (send report etc)

after when i check the event long i got following log

[image]

can you please what is this error ? and how to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use a patch!

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;958644

Have you been updating/virus-scanning etc?